# How to filter contours of arrows in a flowchart image using Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image of flowchart and I need to get contours of all the arrows present in the flowchart and store them in a list.

Please refer the image example from this link:

https://www.esmo.org/living-guidelines/esmo-metastatic-breast-cancer-living-guideline/her2-positive-breast-cancer/her2-positive-breast-cancer/first-and-second-lines

I have all the contours (including the contours of text boxes) in list called 'contours' using the code below:

`contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

Can anyone please let me know how should I separate contours of arrows from all contours?

Comment: Please always provide a reproducible amount of code and an image.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).